# How to set mysql_protocol_tcp in Objective C Mysql client

Tags: mysql, ios, ssh, port, forward

I downloaded Karl Kraft's MySQL source and libraries and built a mysql client lib for iOS 6.  It worked beautifully the very first time on the local mysql database.  Even handled blob data nicely.

The next step was to port forward to a remote database.  After downloading various libraries and tearing out my hair, I went looking for a packaged solution.

I downloaded Chilkat's SSH Tunnel library (free 30 day trial -- and $149 -- worth it all).  That worked the first time too.  It was a pleasure after days and daze of not building, not linking, not compiling, not finding symbols for i386 blah blah blah!!

OK, so here is the kicker.  I now want to work with a remote database.  When I did the 3306 ssh port forward through ssh port 22 to 3306 on a database machine behind the firewall.  Now I turn off mysqld, and my host is localhost port 3306.  I have a slight problem with mysql.

The default start of the client on a UNIX/MAC machine is looking for a socket connection on localhost.

I get the following error:

> Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (38)

I need a TCP protocol start option for mysql.  With a command line, it is easy --protocol=TCP.

With the iOS client lib, it is not readily apparent.  I did a search and in the mysql.h we have the mysql_protocol_type and the constants MYSQL_PROTOCOL_DEFAULT, MYSQL_PROTOCOL_TCP etc etc.

The missing knowledge that I have, is how to set the option programatically in Objective C.

There is a server object that just defines the parameters (server, name, ports, username, password) and the next object is a connection object that calls mysql_init().  Does anyone have any clues on how to do this?

BTW:  Karl Kraft and the guy from ChilKat should have their blood preserved for posterity.  They saved me a lot of time.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Took me a while to figure this out.  With the MySQL client, if you specify connection to 'localhost', it tries to connect with a UNIX socket at either /tmp/mysql.sock or /var/lib/mysql.sock.  However if you specify localhost as 127.0.0.1, then it connects with a TCP protocol equivalent to --protocol=TCP.